# SDL_Renderer opengl conflict

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

I'm new to openGL and SDL and I'm having some problems with a basic program I wrote. I've narrowed it down and it seems like the problem is a conflict between the SDL_CreateRenderer function and how SDL manages OpenGL.

Basically the program is a simple game, drawn with OpenGL, and the problem has risen with me creating a menu. Since the game window was created with the "SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL" flag, I created another window for the menu. Whenever I need to switch between game and menu I just hide and show whichever window I need. To draw on the menu window though I need to create a renderer but after doing so, if I try to go back to the OpenGL window everything crashes catastrophically (computer slows down, everything is unresponsive...).

Can anyone guess where the problem could lie? Or can anyone suggest a better way to solve my game-menu problem?

Comment: You'll need to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok! I'm working on it! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Are you switching GL context back to your initial window? Maybe software renderer will solve it for you, although I don't understand why you needed separate window in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to inter-op OpenGL and SDL_Renderer: even if you *could* guarantee that your platform did/did not implement SDL_Renderer in terms of OpenGL the SDL_Renderer API doesn't have any way to properly set/restore the OpenGL state that SDL_Renderer uses.